# error using R package brms

Tags: r, compiler-errors, r-package

I would like to use the R package `brms`, but I get an error that I do not manage to interpret. It might have to do with `Rtools`, which is however installed on my computer.

This is an example from the `brms` package:

```
 fit1 <- brm(count ~ log_Age_c + log_Base4_c * Trt_c 
        + (1|patient) + (1|visit) + (1|obs), 
        data = epilepsy, family = poisson(), 
        prior = c(set_prior("student_t(5,0,10)", class = "b"),
                  set_prior("cauchy(0,2)", class = "sd")))
```

And this is the error I get:

> Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) :
>   Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created!
>   c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++: not found
>   make: *** [file202834c75e9.o] Error 127
>   Warning message:
>   l'exécution de la commande 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk"   SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)'   SHLIB="file202834c75e9.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file202834c75e9.o"'   renvoie un statut 2
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file202834c75e9.cpp   2> file202834c75e9.cpp.err.txt' had status 1

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it is a problem with Rtools. What does `system("g++ -v")` give you? If it is status 127, Rtools cannot be found by R. Most likely, you haven't checked the box during Rtools installation where you were asked to amend the system path. I suggest that you unintall Rtools and install it again making sure to check the box. Please also verify that you are using the correct version of Rtools compatible with your R version.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already uninstalled and installed Rtools again before and made sure that the version was compatible. However it did not solve the problem. When I do `system("g++ -v")` I do not get an error but a long list of paths, which I do not understand (too long for this comment).

Comment: If you get a list of paths, Rtools can be called in R, so no problem from this side. However, the problem still appears to be Rtools related. Maybe you could ask your question at the Stan users group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/stan-users/general) since this is likely related to Stan itself (brms only provides an interface)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will ask.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my installation of `rstan`.  The problem occurred with RTools33. Installing RTools34 seemed to fix the problem, although I now get the following warning:

```
In find_rtools() :

  WARNING: Rtools 3.4 found on the path at c:/Rtools is not compatible with R 3.3.1.

Please download and install Rtools 3.3 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/, remove the incompatible version from your PATH, then run find_rtools().
```

So far this warning appears benign.

Comment: See https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/327 which suggests the warning is benign and will go away in future versions of `rstan`.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other answers solve this issue, go into your R distribution and open

`R-{version}\etc\x64\Makeconf`

and change `BINPREF` on line 19 to whatever the path to your mingw_64\bin directory is.

Comment: Is there a way to change this in R's console? I don't have write access to c: and RTools is installed in another location...

Comment: You can try `path <- strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")[[1]]`
`new_path <- c(rtools, gcc, path)`
`new_path <- new_path[!duplicated(tolower(new_path))]`
`Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(new_path, collapse = ";"))` 
where `rtools` and `gcc` are strings containing the path, but this didn't work for me. I actually installed R to the Desktop to get around not having access to C:.

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to make it work with Makevars file. posted answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error:" c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++: not found" I located RBuildTools folder on the C: drive, found the g++ file in the bin folder, copied the mingw_64 folder (or wherever your g++ file is located), created an Rtools folder on C: and pasted the mingw_64 folder.  This will create the C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/ path you need to compile R code using the stan( ) function.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the rStan wiki [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Windows#configuration) on Windows Configuration.

Also instead of hacking `Makevars` in c:\ you can create your personal by following the instruction [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Customizing-package-compilation).

In my `%HOM%\.R\Makevars.win64` file I have

CXXFLAGS=-O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function
BINPREF="H:/RTools/mingw_64/bin/"

This resolved my issue.